# Unable to send custom events with SSE and PHP

Tags: php, server-sent-events, eventsource

I have Server Sent Events (SSE) working with the default message type.  But I'm unable to get a custom event type to work.

On the client I have

```
const sse = new 
EventSource('/api/events/transaction-event');
sse.onopen = (d=>console.log(d))

sse.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
  console.log('message')
  console.log(e)
})

sse.addEventListener("test", function(e) {
  console.log('test')
  console.log(e)
})
```

On the server I have

```
class Events
{
    public function test(Request $request){
      $response = new StreamedResponse(function() use ($request) {
        while(true) {

          // echo('event: test\n');
          echo 'data: ' . json_encode(['hello'=>'world']) . "\n\n";
          ob_flush();
          flush();
          sleep(2);
        }
      });
      $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/event-stream');
      $response->headers->set('Connection', 'keep');
      $response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
      return $response;
    }

}
```

Running this code, you can see the `event: test\n` is commented out, and I get the SSE with type `message` in my browser.  But if I uncomment the `event: test\n` to try and change the event type to `test`, the client side listener does not invoke ( nor does the default `message` type).  Am I missing something here??  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change the quotes from :

```
// echo('event: test\n');
```

To :

```
echo("event: test\n");
```

To allow new line to be processed

Answer (score 0):

This echo("event: test\n"); or echo('event: test\n'); are the same and will both give an error:undefined 'custom variable name'.It seems the best is to just rely on data field and assign it a string array of events as e index then json parse it back 2 array n use it from there.

Else if you are comfortable with working with a an eventsrc script that 1st throws that error then work normal afterwards just go for any way suggested above methods including yours.

It seems t was jus designed to have that bad functional error i guess as there is no solution yet even now.

Comment: The best way imo to sent events from server to client is to setup websockets with a node server